# $G$: group. $M,N\leq G$ s.t. $x^{-1}Mx\subset M$ & $x^{-1}Nx\subset N, \forall x\in G$. Prove $MN\leq G$ & $x^{-1}(MN)x\subset MN, \forall x\in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

**Problem:** $G$ is a group and $M,N\leq G$ s.t. $x^{-1}Mx\subset M$ & $x^{-1}Nx\subset N, \forall x\in G$. Prove $MN\leq G$ & $x^{-1}(MN)x\subset MN, \forall x\in G$.

My sketch of **solution**:

I know that

> If $A,B\leq G$ s.t. $b^{-1}Ab\subset A, \forall b\in B$, then $AB\leq G$.

By that I can conclude easily that $MN\leq G$. (*or do I?*)

To show the second part, I simply let $x^{-1}(mn)x\in x^{-1}MNx$ and show that it's in $MN$. To do so, let $x^{-1}mx\in M$ & $x^{-1}nx\in N$, thus

$$(x^{-1}mx)(x^{-1}nx)\in MN\Rightarrow x^{-1}mnx\in MN$$

Anything I miss?

Comment: What is $G$?  Is it a group?  Are $M,N$ subgroups?  You jumped into the details without giving the Reader a decent context for what problem is being posed.

Comment: @hardmath yes, sorry! $G$ is a group and $M,N$ are subgroups.

Comment: A group theorist might pose this as showing the *join* $MN$ of two normal subgroups $M,N$ of $G$ is again a normal subgroup of $G$.